# Super user privileges Azure CloudShell?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I see that one has elevated permissions on the Cloud Shell console.

However for some operation the shell throws errors that seem to be related to privileges.

For example, using the `tar` command resulted for me in errors:

> utime: operation not permitted

The archive was properly extracted, though - so I am not sure why any errors are being thrown.

Comment: In Azure CloudShell, we don't have the root permission and we also could not use `sudo`.

Comment: Maybe you could check this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/699225/avoid-errors-from-tar-failing-to-restore-directory-permissions). Also, if possible, could you share your target directory? In `/home/<user>/` or other?

Answer (score 2):

Walter is correct, you are set as a regular Linux user when using Bash in Cloud Shell. As a result any cmds that may require sudo or root permissions will fail. If this is key to your scenario, please provide more details - in addition we're always listening to feedback at aka.ms/cloudshellfeedback

Thanks for being a Cloud Shell user, I hope it has been useful for you thus far!